# Shell how to add text to an already created line

Tags: shell, text, line

What I'm trying to say is i want to add "C" to this already written .txt file:

a:b:c
b:c:a

and make it like:

a:C:c
b:c:a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/a:b:c/a:C:c/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! not the most efficient, but it'll do!